# Alarming Probationary Period?

Tags: new-job, probation

My probationary period was extended last week, all the sudden, two weeks before due date.

The official reason was that I didn't work on an unclear task I couldn't do, and due to my "senior" status, I should be able to do it.

I haven't had enough time to learn enough, nor did I work on that specific component to investigate the source of the problem. This problem exists since many years and no one could solve it (it happens randomly under unclear conditions/parameters etc.).

The unspoken reason is that I didn't contact my boss to inform her about the status of a previous task. My boss is sometimes absent without prior notice nor does she bother to reveal the duration of her absence.

I don't like this new job because we work without any methodology.

When someting wrong happens, she keeps telling me: I gave you (verbally) the information yesterday (no documents, nothing written --> high risk of confusion) - my colleagues tell me "tell her yes, you are right".

My problem with her is that when I was proactive, she shut me down, and now that I am being passive, she doesn't like it.

At the end of last week, I could see she was not happy because she could see my office was empty (already prepared my bags - I don't like my new job either, but I have to cope with it).

She kind of marginalized me lately, or maybe wanted me to be more proactive as before.

She gave me a long tedious mechanical task (I had to produce +6000 lines of hard coded values). While executing this task, I was wondering: "is she punishing me?"

When I called her to tell her I was done, she sounded energetic and positive.

However, I heard she has a hard time keeping subordinates, as she usually get into conflicts even people with soft personalities.

Am I losing this job?

Is she inciting me to look for another job?

Comment: As asked, I suspect this is unanswerable.  We have no way of knowing what your boss intends to do or is trying to incite you to do. That being said, it certainly seems like a toxic environment, and I'm not in the least bit surprised that she has trouble keeping subordinates.  If I were you I'd prepare to leave regardless of what *she* wants.

Comment: "I don't like this new job because we work without any methodology" then you know what to do ... polish your resume

Comment: You do realize a probation period goes both ways, right? If you don't like how you're treated, you can leave.

Answer (score 3):

It's your choice to bail on this job now or redefine it as something you can succeed at.

Since it seems she has no idea what to do with you I'd find something, anything, useful and productive to do. Run it by her first. Don't go working on unassigned stuff. But think about your talents, their needs, and identify things you really can help with. Ask around and learn what people do here. Talk to as many as you can. In many ways you're more qualified to find stuff you can help with than management is. But again, don't work on it without permission. Don't make her look bad by just flat out asking others for work she didn't assign you. Just learn about the company and take ideas to her.

Also, if you really are senior you should be qualified to set a methodology. If you believe the place needs one create one. Methodologies aren't handed down from heaven.